# Create a new aggregate collection from two existing collections?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, database

I have a unique field in two collections which is "ip".  One collection contains machine data and the other contains geographic data

Is there a way to aggregate data from two collections and create a third collection with this data?

For example:

`geo:`

`"ip" : "1.1.1.1", "lat" : 1.29, "lon" : 103.86`

`"ip" : "2.2.2.2", "lat" : 1.29, "lon" : 103.86`

`machines:`

`"ip" : "1.1.1.1", "load" : 5`

`"ip" : "2.2.2.2", "load" : 7`

`## becomes a new collection`

`"lat" : 1.29, "lon" : 103.86, "load" : 12`

I am using the Python driver for MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is a way to do it with $out statement

let's say that you have two collections "pc" and "geo" and you are going to create collection "allData" - and mongo query will look like this:

```
db.pc.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from:"geo"  ,
        localfield:"ip",
        foreginField:"ip",
        as: geoData
    }
},
{
    $unwind:"$geoData"
},
```

> [{$project:{transform document as needed}},](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)

```
{
    $out    :"allData"
}   
])
```

To shape your allData collection you can use $project to add/remove fields as desired.

Comment: Finally got around to running this.  I had to create some indexes to speed it up, but this is what I was looking for.  Thank you!